# How can I detect a global drag event ?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a window to drop a file in. What I would like to do is being able to change the appareance of the window when the user start to drag something on his desktop for example (So not on the window).

For that I need to catch a global event from window. This event is called GiveFeedBack I think (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.givefeedback(v=vs.110).aspx) ? But how can I detect it on Qt ?

Thanks

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at, but this could probably be a good question if you add a little more detail and an example of what you are trying to do to the question itself, rather than have us read through the MS documentation and try to guess.

Comment: I have a small frameless window on my desktop, what I want to do is change the appearance of this small window (With for example a "DROP HERE") when the user is starting to drag something on his desktop. The problem I have is that I don't know how to do it since it's a global event. I searched for some kind of a "start dragging" event and found the link above but I've never used something like that so I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: maybe with the [native event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#installNativeEventFilter) checking for `windows_generic_MSG` events. You'd have to subclass `QAbstractNativeEventFilter ` and provide your own `winEventFilter`, at least with Qt5.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to use the Native Event Filter but I could not make it work (I'm farily new with Qt). Could you give me an example on how to use it and how tu subclass it ?

Comment: I'll try to put something together. Full disclaimer though, a) I'm not a windows event expert, and b) I'm not a big believer in platform specific code. Unless it's a direct-from-the-customer-shall-statement requirement, I think you're better off trying to work with the Qt system, instead of trying to shoehorn it into being a c# style program. The Qt way of doing things is to show the drop indicator once the drag is above the main window.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a windows hook for mouse events and look out for potential drag/drops or alternatively add hooks onto message procs of windows from other running processes (not particularly nice).

UAC may stop this working in some cases.

See:
[SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx)

There may also be some COM interfaces for this.  But you may not get events when the drag starts.  See [RegisterDragDrop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.